# Horizontal Layout with columns: how to automatically adjust the container size with a fixed column size and an unknown number of columns

Tags: css, height, overflow, multiple-columns, horizontal-scrolling

I would like to build a page with a **horizontal layout**. The page consists of three blocks: an abstract, a rather **long article organized in columns** and a bibliographic reference block.

The blocks must be organized horizontally only (**no vertical scrolling**). I would like to obtain horizontal scrolling for all blocks (no fixed blocks or only one block with scrolling).

My problem is that by using a fixed height and an undetermined number of columns, I only get two columns and the rest overflow on the last div

**How to make sure that the size of the central div with column is correct?**

---

Here is a screenshot of the problem : the yellow div has the size of the first columns. The rest of the content overflows to the last div which should normally be at the end.

The content of the article section flows into the following : https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0Api.png

And here is the best i managed to do so far (I use js only to generate random content) :

My example page :

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chance/1.0.18/chance.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="paper" row text-center>
        <div id="info">
            <h2>Abstract</h2>
            <p id="abstract"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
        </div>
        <div id="more">
            <h2>More</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function getRandomInt(max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
        }

        $("#abstract").append(chance.paragraph({
            sentences: 7
        }));

        $("#content").append("<h1>" + chance.paragraph({
            sentences: 1
        }) + "</h1>");
        $("#content").append("<h2>" + chance.paragraph({
            sentences: 1
        }) + "</h2>");

        for (var i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
            if (Math.random() > 0.8) {
                $("#content").append("<h2>" + chance.paragraph({
                    sentences: 1
                }) + "</h2>");
            }
            $("#content").append("<p>" + chance.paragraph({
                sentences: getRandomInt(10)
            }) + "</p>");
        }

        $("#more").append(chance.paragraph({
            sentences: 7
        }));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS :

```
#paper{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background : white;
    overflow-x : scroll;
}

#paper > div{
    height : 96vh;
}

#info{
    background : yellowgreen;
}
#content{
    columns: 300px ;
    column-gap: 100px;
    background : yellow;
}
#more{
    background : pink;
}
```

]

It's for personnal use. I don't need to support old browser versions. The latest versions of Firefox and Chrome or using js is fine.

**Solution 1 :** I have found a solution that works with javascript:
I'm not sure it's very elegant, though. I suspect there must be a more acceptable solution. Any comments will be welcome.

```
 $('#content').css("min-width",(document.getElementById('content').scrollWidth + "px"))
```